# How to increment and display different values with different buttons

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

In this part of the code:

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
    String pub = resultSet.getString("text_pub");
    if (pub==null) {
        pub = "";
    }
    String photo = resultSet.getString("path_photo");
%>
    <tr bgcolor="#8FBC8F">
        <td><%= pub %></td>
<%
    if (photo!=null) {
%>
        <td><img src="images/<%=photo%>" width="150" height="130"></td>
<%
    }%>
       <script>         
       var a = 1;
            function increase(){

                var textBox = document.getElementById("text");
                textBox.value = a;
                a++;
            }            
        </script>

 <td><button type="button" name="j'aime" onclick="increase()">j'aime</button>
        <input type="text" id="text" width="50"></td>


<%}
%>
```

I have different publications displayed in a tab in each row I have a like (j'aime) button and each time I click on it a variable is incremented and displyed in a text field in the same row, the problem is that no matter what button I click on it's always the first value of the first row  that is incremented.

Comment: Do you have multiple inputs with the same id?

Comment: it's because the button and the input are in the while loop, so yes in each row the id is the same, I don't know how to give each input a different id to make it work.

Comment: @maroua add index to id's: `id="text_1"`, `id="text_2"`

Answer (score 0):

you can write your javascript code like this -

onclick of the button find the immediate parent tr of the button then find a child input of that tr and then increment value.

in this way you can increment the value of input exactly in same row.
I am not comfortable with javascript so i can give you code sample although in jquery i can easily do it, but it won't help.

You can write your increase function like i said